# Using Naive Bayes to do multi classification

Tags: python, text-classification, naivebayes

I have a dataset as below:

```
data = [[92, 155],
 [56, 186, 117, 210, 224],
 [247, 202, 189, 210, 65, 3, 270, 224],
 [20, 14, 157, 224],
 [17, 89, 158, 224],
 [263, 283, 68, 224],
 [182, 166, 224],
 [176, 37, 100, 224],
 [33, 102, 41, 269, 177, 224],
 [0, 260, 49, 207, 278, 217, 35],
 [119],
 [118],
 [142, 185, 7, 246, 224],
 [104, 22, 101, 224],
 [84, 205, 224],
 [225, 93, 54, 224],
 [98, 32, 78, 224],
 [159, 217, 212, 198, 224],
 [178, 94, 187, 224],
 [211, 149, 193, 149, 66, 139, 67, 28, 106, 224],
 [133, 151],
 [259, 109, 29, 224],
 [215, 241, 73, 255, 77, 144, 224],
 [36, 254, 19, 268, 183, 224],
 [47, 234, 203, 111, 231, 141, 30],
 [127, 275, 220, 161],
 [214, 267, 22, 90, 224],
 [46, 217, 103],
 [17, 89, 128, 224],
 [225, 22, 101, 224],
 [285, 265, 151],
 [215, 206, 264, 43, 224],
 [244, 21, 224],
 [82, 122, 240, 5, 224],
 [259, 136, 162, 194, 224],
 [176, 208, 112, 224],
 [172, 19, 146, 276, 31, 246, 51, 224],
 [45, 10],
 [229, 24, 224],
 [143, 108, 239, 224],
 [225, 282, 83, 224],
 [110, 267, 171],
 [176, 245, 95, 123, 270, 224],
 [248, 195, 139, 261, 173, 281, 232, 80, 18, 224],
 [61, 60, 233],
 [211, 120, 1, 23],
 [225, 267, 249, 224],
 [247, 202, 86, 196, 224],
 [15, 127, 222, 224],
 [247, 202, 186, 226, 145, 224],
 [174, 242, 196, 224],
 [259, 152, 71, 224],
 [235, 44, 230, 224],
 [69, 96, 50, 99, 116],
 [259, 279, 224],
 [228, 70],
 [39, 139, 201, 190, 224],
 [132, 40, 219, 81, 224],
 [159, 221, 224],
 [267, 16, 6, 62],
 [143, 59, 175, 129, 48, 224],
 [280, 140, 224],
 [284, 124, 167, 150, 274],
 [113, 265, 184],
 [179, 4, 257, 145, 224],
 [247, 202, 72, 11, 224],
 [64],
 [192, 125, 105],
 [174, 134, 224],
 [58, 139, 85, 160, 209, 224],
 [130, 169, 137, 256, 224],
 [215, 163, 265, 185, 26],
 [176, 147, 74, 224],
 [0, 266],
 [143, 34, 153, 188, 224],
 [121],
 [243, 75, 135],
 [38, 218, 199, 253, 224],
 [178, 271, 224],
 [154, 164, 180, 27, 270, 224],
 [176, 189, 148, 139, 277, 224],
 [57, 62],
 [91, 168, 251, 224],
 [172, 19, 146, 276, 53, 97, 200, 224],
 [64],
 [8, 237, 224],
 [138, 107, 224],
 [176, 238, 224],
 [204, 217, 63, 165, 224],
 [215, 216, 272, 62, 170, 2, 55, 224],
 [247, 273, 202, 223, 9, 148, 224],
 [258, 267, 181, 224],
 [262, 76, 126, 12, 224],
 [36, 254, 19, 268, 250, 213, 48, 224],
 [227, 42],
 [79, 197, 52, 87, 224],
 [143, 131, 224],
 [156, 88, 115, 236, 224],
 [259, 13, 252, 224],
 [114, 25, 191, 224]]

target = [9,
 31,
 20,
 9,
 3,
 26,
 16,
 11,
 28,
 0,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 7,
 1,
 33,
 9,
 13,
 15,
 9,
 21,
 9,
 34,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 3,
 1,
 9,
 27,
 14,
 22,
 21,
 11,
 17,
 9,
 6,
 8,
 1,
 9,
 11,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 1,
 20,
 29,
 20,
 23,
 21,
 9,
 9,
 21,
 9,
 18,
 9,
 9,
 30,
 8,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 20,
 9,
 32,
 23,
 9,
 24,
 9,
 11,
 9,
 8,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 13,
 10,
 11,
 9,
 12,
 17,
 9,
 5,
 9,
 11,
 9,
 2,
 20,
 9,
 25,
 34,
 9,
 9,
 8,
 4,
 21,
 19]
```

I wish to do classification by using naive bayes or any other BEST algorithms available. However, I received error when using naive bayes as below:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

mnb = MultinomialNB(class_prior=[.25,.75])
mnb.fit(data, target)
```

Errros:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[list([92, 155]) list([56, 186, 117, 210, 224])
 list([247, 202, 189, 210, 65, 3, 270, 224]) list([20, 14, 157, 224])
 list([17, 89, 158, 224]) list([263, 283, 68, 224]) list([182, 166, 224])
 list([176, 37, 100, 224]) list([33, 102, 41, 269, 177, 224])
 list([0, 260, 49, 207, 278, 217, 35]) list([119]) list([118])
 list([142, 185, 7, 246, 224]) list([104, 22, 101, 224])
 list([84, 205, 224]) list([225, 93, 54, 224]) list([98, 32, 78, 224])
 list([159, 217, 212, 198, 224]) list([178, 94, 187, 224])
 list([211, 149, 193, 149, 66, 139, 67, 28, 106, 224]) list([133, 151])
 list([259, 109, 29, 224]) list([215, 241, 73, 255, 77, 144, 224])
 list([36, 254, 19, 268, 183, 224])
 list([47, 234, 203, 111, 231, 141, 30]) list([127, 275, 220, 161])
 list([214, 267, 22, 90, 224]) list([46, 217, 103])
 list([17, 89, 128, 224]) list([225, 22, 101, 224]) list([285, 265, 151])
 list([215, 206, 264, 43, 224]) list([244, 21, 224])
 list([82, 122, 240, 5, 224]) list([259, 136, 162, 194, 224])
 list([176, 208, 112, 224]) list([172, 19, 146, 276, 31, 246, 51, 224])
 list([45, 10]) list([229, 24, 224]) list([143, 108, 239, 224])
 list([225, 282, 83, 224]) list([110, 267, 171])
 list([176, 245, 95, 123, 270, 224])
 list([248, 195, 139, 261, 173, 281, 232, 80, 18, 224])
 list([61, 60, 233]) list([211, 120, 1, 23]) list([225, 267, 249, 224])
 list([247, 202, 86, 196, 224]) list([15, 127, 222, 224])
 list([247, 202, 186, 226, 145, 224]) list([174, 242, 196, 224])
 list([259, 152, 71, 224]) list([235, 44, 230, 224])
 list([69, 96, 50, 99, 116]) list([259, 279, 224]) list([228, 70])
 list([39, 139, 201, 190, 224]) list([132, 40, 219, 81, 224])
 list([159, 221, 224]) list([267, 16, 6, 62])
 list([143, 59, 175, 129, 48, 224]) list([280, 140, 224])
 list([284, 124, 167, 150, 274]) list([113, 265, 184])
 list([179, 4, 257, 145, 224]) list([247, 202, 72, 11, 224]) list([64])
 list([192, 125, 105]) list([174, 134, 224])
 list([58, 139, 85, 160, 209, 224]) list([130, 169, 137, 256, 224])
 list([215, 163, 265, 185, 26]) list([176, 147, 74, 224]) list([0, 266])
 list([143, 34, 153, 188, 224]) list([121]) list([243, 75, 135])
 list([38, 218, 199, 253, 224]) list([178, 271, 224])
 list([154, 164, 180, 27, 270, 224]) list([176, 189, 148, 139, 277, 224])
 list([57, 62]) list([91, 168, 251, 224])
 list([172, 19, 146, 276, 53, 97, 200, 224]) list([64])
 list([8, 237, 224]) list([138, 107, 224]) list([176, 238, 224])
 list([204, 217, 63, 165, 224]) list([215, 216, 272, 62, 170, 2, 55, 224])
 list([247, 273, 202, 223, 9, 148, 224]) list([258, 267, 181, 224])
 list([262, 76, 126, 12, 224]) list([36, 254, 19, 268, 250, 213, 48, 224])
 list([227, 42]) list([79, 197, 52, 87, 224]) list([143, 131, 224])
 list([156, 88, 115, 236, 224]) list([259, 13, 252, 224])
 list([114, 25, 191, 224])].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Please can anyone please help me with this? Or can someone show me some other best examples of algorithms to use for machine learning like decision tree, svm or anything.

Comment: Each row in data must be of the same length.

Comment: yes but what i wanted to do is to classify the whole tokenized_sequences row and map it to the target. Isnt that possible? It like text classification if not mistaken.

Comment: you can try padding the data with zeros to ensure every row has the same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the direct answer to why you're getting an error is that you're passing an array of lists as an argument. Sklearn thus think you're passing in a 1D array of lists. It is not possible to transform your `data` to a 2D matrix because the number of values in your list in inconsistent.

From my understanding (which could be wrong), each row of your input feature matrix need to have the same amount of numbers. Given this is satisfied, then you should be able to feed your data into `MultinomialNB` no problem.

Consider padding with zeros:

```py
data1 = np.zeros((len(data), 10))
for i in range(len(data)):
    data1[i, :len(data[i])] = data[i]
```

Comment: yes but what i wanted to do is to classify the whole tokenized_sequences row and map it to the target. Isnt that possible? It like text classification if not mistaken.

Comment: How did you generate your tokenized sequence?

Comment: i found the issue is here. 

array([array([ 92, 155,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
       array([ 56, 186, 117, 210, 224,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]),
       array([247, 202, 189, 210,  65,   3, 270, 224,   0,   0]), dtype=object)

Is there a way to reshape it to (3,10)

Comment: I made an edit that shows you how to pad your entire 2d `data` array with zero and into a numpy matrix. Hope it helps. Is that your question?